# Comparar 2 array distintos longitudes

Tags: javascript

necesito su ayuda, tengo 2 arreglos con distintos tamaños de longitud.

```
var arr = [{id: 1, name: 'es'}, {id: 2, name: 'es'}, {id: 3, name: 'es'}, {id: 4, name: 'es'}]

var arr_select = [{id: 3, name: 'es'}, {id: 1, name: 'es'}, {id: 3, name: 'es'}]
```

La idea es recorrer con un `for` y los que se repite, escribir un

```
    if(si existen) document.write('<option selected>'+data+'</option>');
    else
        los no seleccionados
        document.write('<option selected>'+data+'</option>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hola Edinson aquí te dejo el código para que obtengas los repetidos y los no repetidos, haces una comparación del arreglo que contiene todo con el arreglo que tiene algunos y mediante una variable booleana (var en javascript) determinas si se repite o no.

```
    var arr = [{id: 1, name: 'es'}, {id: 2, name: 'es'}, {id: 3, name: 'es'}, {id: 4, name: 'es'}]
    var arr_select = [{id: 3, name: 'es'}, {id: 1, name: 'es'}, {id: 3, name: 'es'}]
    var arr_repetido = new Array();
    var arr_no_repetido = new Array();

   arr.forEach(x=> //recorremos todos los elementos del primero arreglo
   {
        var repetido = false;
        arr_select.forEach(y=> //recorremos todos los elementos del segundo arreglo
        {
            if(x.id === y.id) //comparamos si se repite los elementos
            {
                repetido = true; //si se repite entonces cambiamos el estado
                return; //retornamos porque ya sabemos que se repite y no necesitamos comparar en este arreglo
            }
        });

        if(repetido) //aqui viene el estado después de ser evaluado y aquí puedes hacer lo que desees
            arr_repetido.push(x);
        else
            arr_no_repetido.push(x);
   });


   console.log(arr_repetido);
   console.log(arr_no_repetido);
```

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Te agrego una solucion, revisa la implementacion del barrido y la comparacion.
Lo siguiente tomando en cuenta el valor de todos los campos en los objetos, es decir {id: 1, name: 'es'} es diferente de {id=1, name="us"}

```js
var arreglo1 = [{id: 1, name: 'es'}, {id: 2, name: 'es'}, {id: 3, name: 'es'}, {id: 4, name: 'es'}]

var arreglo2 = [{id: 3, name: 'es'}, {id: 1, name: 'es'}, {id: 3, name: 'es'}]


//funcion comparacion de elementos.
const esIgual=function(obj1,obj2){

  var iguales= JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2);
//console.log('iegual? '+ iguales);
 return iguales;
}

//agrega nuevos elementos a un arreglo
function AgregaSiNoExiste(arr, obj) {
    const index = arr.findIndex((e) => e.id === obj.id);

    if (index === -1) {
        arr.push(obj);
    } else {
        arr[index] = obj;
    }
}

const elementosIguales=[];
const elementosDiferentes=[]

const compara= function(arr1,arr2)
{
   //relativo igual.
 arr1.forEach((e1) =>{ arr2.forEach((e2) =>{
   var elementoIgual=false;
   if(esIgual(e1,e2) ){
    elementoIgual=true;
   } 
   if(elementoIgual)
     AgregaSiNoExiste(elementosIguales,e1); 
 })
 
 });

}

compara(arreglo1,arreglo2);

console.log(elementosIguales);
//console.log(elementosDiferentes);
```

Como ejercicio final debes implementar como llenar el array de elementosDiferentes.